# Open Graph video player not working in Facebook post

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

We have added the Facebook Open Graph tags to our video player, which worked a few months ago, however now it seems like something was changed that has broken integration. The Open Graph debugger shows that it is able to read all of the information, but the post does not show the image or the video player.

Is there something that we are missing or are Open Graph video players broken now?

Test link: https://player.rbmtv.com/2ac
Debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

Comment: If it worked before and stopped working file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: I will do that if no one else has any ideas, it happened after a major rewrite of our player so maybe something is wrong on our end.